# How to add "Project Description" in FogBugz?

Tags: fogbugz

When I create a new project (or even when I edit the Sample Project) there is no way to add Description to the project.

Or am I blind to the obvious?

Comment: How is this question a programming related question? Or do we let it slide cause the creater of FogBugz happens to be one of the creators of this website? :P

Comment: OK, I agree its not a programming question! But it is programming related. Remember, What is the best programming chair is a valid question here :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no such thing as a project description, really. There's a column in the Projects page which is used so you can see which project is the default, built-in inbox, and we couldn't think of anything better to put as the column header for that column.

Answer (score 8):

You are not crazy.  It is used internally and not even stored in the database.  I wondered the same thing when I first started using FogBugz, but found a forum entry to answer my question.  As of today, I still don't think they have implemented it.  Jump over to FogCreek and submit a request, if you would like to make it editable.

- ["Description" missing from Project?](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.7698.2)
- [How to Edit a Project Description](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.21635.2)

Answer (score 0):

The description is mostly for system projects, like e-mail inbox.

You might be able to set one in the underlying DB table.